# Why does Expected<T> in LLVM implement two constructors for Expected<T>&&?

Tags: c++, llvm

`Expected<T>` is implemented in llvm/Support/Error.h. It is a tagged union holding either a `T` or an `Error`.

`Expected<T>` is a template class with type `T`:

```
template <class T> class LLVM_NODISCARD Expected
```

But these two constructors really confuse me:

```
  /// Move construct an Expected<T> value from an Expected<OtherT>, where OtherT
  /// must be convertible to T.
  template <class OtherT>
  Expected(Expected<OtherT> &&Other,
           typename std::enable_if<std::is_convertible<OtherT, T>::value>::type
               * = nullptr) {
    moveConstruct(std::move(Other));
  }

  /// Move construct an Expected<T> value from an Expected<OtherT>, where OtherT
  /// isn't convertible to T.
  template <class OtherT>
  explicit Expected(
      Expected<OtherT> &&Other,
      typename std::enable_if<!std::is_convertible<OtherT, T>::value>::type * =
          nullptr) {
    moveConstruct(std::move(Other));
  }
```

Why does `Expected<T>` repeat two constructs for the same implementation? Why doesn't it do it like this?:

```
template <class OtherT>
Expected(Expected<OtherT>&& Other) { moveConstruct(std::move(Other));}
```

Comment: Note the `explicit` keyword

Comment: I want to know why `explicit` keyword matters here? Could anyone give an example?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because that constructor is **conditionally explicit** according to the proposal. This means that the constructor is *explicit only if some condition is met* (here, convertibility of `T` and `OtherT`).

C++ does not have a mechanism for this functionality (something as `explicit(condition)`) before C++20. Implementations thus need to use some other mechanism, such as a **definition of two different constructors** — one *explicit* and another one *converting* — and ensure the selection of the proper constructor according to the condition. This is typically done via SFINAE with the help of `std::enable_if`, where the condition is resolved.

---

Since C++20, there should be a conditional version of the `explicit` specifier. The implementation then would be much easier with a single definition:

```
template <class OtherT>
explicit(!std::is_convertible_v<OtherT, T>)
Expected(Expected<OtherT> &&Other)
{
   moveConstruct(std::move(Other));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Although I am still confused, I got lots of resources after googling 'conditionally explicit' .

Comment: @yodahaji Note that _conditionally explicit_ is not a standard term. It simply means that the constructor is _explicit_ or _converting_ according to some condition.

Answer (score 5):

To understand this we should start with `std::is_convertible`. According to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_convertible):

> If the imaginary function definition `To test() { return std::declval<From>(); }` is well-formed, (that is, either `std::declval<From>()` can be converted to `To` using implicit conversions, or both `From` and `To` are possibly cv-qualified void), provides the member constant value equal to `true`. Otherwise value is `false`. For the purposes of this check, the use of `std::declval` in the return statement is not considered an odr-use.
>
> Access checks are performed as if from a context unrelated to either type. Only the validity of the immediate context of the expression in the return statement (including conversions to the return type) is considered.

The important part here is that it checks for implicit conversions only. Therefore what the two implementations in your OP mean is that if `OtherT` is implicitly convertible to `T`, then `expected<OtherT>` is implicitly convertible to `expected<T>`. If `OtherT` requires an explicit cast to `T`, then `Expected<OtherT>` requires and explicit cast to `Expected<T>`.

Here are examples of implicit and explicit casts and their `Expected` counterparts

```
int x;
long int y = x;              // implicit cast ok
Expected<int> ex;
Expected<long int> ey = ex;  // also ok

void* v_ptr;
int* i_ptr = static_cast<int*>(v_ptr);              // explicit cast required
Expected<void*> ev_ptr;
auto ei_ptr = static_cast<Expected<int*>>(ev_ptr);  // also required
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I can't get the meaning for ' then `Expected<OtherT>` requires an explicit cast to `Expected<T>` mean'. What does the 'explicit cast' here mean? I can't image an example for this.

Comment: Added a few examples to the post to clarify what explicit casts mean. Generally they are used to prevent accidental implicit casts when those would possibly introduce bugs. Unfortunately, I can't test the code right now so if you spot a typo/bug please let me know and I'll fix it.

Comment: This statement 'to prevent accidental implicit casts'  answers my question. Thank you:)